# How to generate heaviest content for regular expression engine?

Tags: regex, algorithm, optimization, pcre

I wonder about the way to automatically generate small but really heavy content to match for a certain regular expression. I mean that for a certain expression I'm looking for the smallest and the heaviest payload.
Formally saying the `heavy` value is
`H = regexp engine work time / content length`
Given that there is a max content length

Example for regexp `([\w%]+=[\w%]*&){500}`:
It takes ~2500 steps to check content matches

```
A=& ... (498 times) ... A=&
```

and it takes ~250 times more steps to check that content doesnt match

```
A=& ... (498 times) ... A=
```

My observations are:

- Regexp starting with a wildchar sequence (for ex.) `/^\w+.../` are the worst for regexp engine
- Generally engine performs more calculations when it tries to match regular expression till the content end i.e. content shouldn't match to regexp at all

What are clue points in building such payloads?

Is it possible to generate such payloads automatically?

Answer (score 1):

`and it takes ~250 times more steps to check that content doesn't match`

However the steps don't give a real indication of performance.

Not sure what you mean by *payload*. But it is always a good idea to test
your regex in failure mode (i.e. get it to fail).

The problem is your regex contains a fixed range, minimum (500) quantifier.

This kicks off the backtracking mechanism, even if your expression doesn't
contain nested quantifiers.

Since you tag PCRE, its better to use one of the backtrack control verbs
somewhere in the expression quantified by the `{500}`.
This will disengage the backtrack mechanism for *that* group.
And at the point in the string where the `(*SKIP)` is matched, the
engine is prohibited to go back.

You can get this app [RegexFormat](http://regexformat.com) for windows
to run some test/benchmark scenarios.  I has a built in benchmark tool.

Time to match:

```
Regex1:   ([\w%]+=(?:[\w%]*&|(*SKIP)(*FAIL))){500}
Completed iterations:   1  /  1     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.26 s,   256.59 ms,   256588 µs
```

Time to fail:

```
Regex1:   ([\w%]+=(?:[\w%]*&|(*SKIP)(*FAIL))){500}
Completed iterations:   1  /  1     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   0
Elapsed Time:    0.27 s,   270.76 ms,   270765 µs
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. My whole idea is about are there regexp features that can lead to the worst performance (of course in failure mode)? I'm going to search for such regular expressions in automatic or semiautomatic mode and exploit them to cause denial-of-service of regexp engine.
I'm on linux so are there any online benchmarking tool?